# Python File Upload If statement and user cancelation

Tags: python, tkinter

I have the following file upload code.  I want to modify this code for two things:
1.If the user cancels the askopenfilenames command, the overall entire program will stop.
2.If the user does not select the required number of files, the function fileupload will restart, until the correct number of files is selected.

```
import Tkinter
from Tkinter import Tk
tk=Tk()
from tkFileDialog import askopenfilenames
import tkMessageBox
def fileupload():
     tk.withdraw()
     uploadedfiles = askopenfilenames(multiple=True)
     ##if user cancels: (IF STATEMENT TO RESULT IN MESSAGEBOX AND CODE TO STOP)
      ###tk.withdraw()
      ###tkMessageBox.showinfo(message="File Upload has been cancelled program will stop")
       ##Stop code

    if len(uploadedfiles)>2 or len(uploadedfiles)<2:
       tk.withdraw()
       tkMessageBox.showinfo(message="2 files have not been selected!")
       ##rerun function to reselect files
   return uploadedfiles
uploadedfiles=fileupload()
print uploadedfiles
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First check if the string returned by `askopenfilenames` is empty, which means that the user closed the dialog. Then use `tk.splitlist` to create a list from the string (if it is not empty) and check its length:

```
tk=Tk()
tk.withdraw()

def fileupload():
    while True:
        uploadedfilenames = askopenfilenames(multiple=True)
        if uploadedfilenames == '':
            tkMessageBox.showinfo(message="File Upload has been cancelled program will stop")
            return
        uploadedfiles = tk.splitlist(uploadedfilenames)
        if len(uploadedfiles)!=2:
           tkMessageBox.showinfo(message="2 files have not been selected!")
        else:
            return uploadedfiles

print fileupload()
```